# Database php design advice

Tags: php, database

So what I am doing right now is a website about games. Its like a Wikipedia of games. I have created already a database of games in phpMyAdmin (I have one table for it, consisting of 6 coulmns, game_ID, game_name, game_category, history, no_of_players and instruction). I have completed already a homepage, login/logout and stuff. The only thing it lacks is the content itself which are the games. I am new to PHP, I don't have much knowledge yet about displaying database and stuff. But what I want to do with my website is to display the list of names of games from the database I made and then users can  click the name and they will be redirected to the page where it displays the whole information about it. I've been trying to figure out how to do it. I am already able to display the list of names on my website but only the list, not the way I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create two php pages for this. For example, index.php and view_post.php

index.Php

The index file will list all games from the games table.
You can fetch all games from database as below :

```
    <?php
    try {

        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

            echo '<div>';
                echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';                
                echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';                
            echo '</div>';

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Viewpost.Php

viewpost.php is used to display any post that has been clicked on.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT postID, postTitle, postCont, postDate FROM blog_posts WHERE postID = :postID');
$stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

For more details take a look at this tutorial [tutorial](https://daveismyname.com/creating-a-blog-from-scratch-with-php-bp)

You can also search on google "how to create blog with php". You will get an idea how to do your project.

Comment: Much appreciated!! It really helped me a lot.